# Logarithm of null-homotopic maps

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, logarithms, homotopy-theory

The logarithm of a $\mathbb{C}^*$-valued function on a smooth manifold $M$ can be defined locally (up to a choice) but in general we cannot patch up these choices so to define it the whole space $M$, what we can always do though is define it globally on its universal cover $\tilde{M}$. However sometimes a function admits a globally defined logarithm (up to a choice) even when the domain is not simply connected, e.g. the constant function.

**Question:** How can I prove that a null-homotopic map from $M$ to $S^1\subset\mathbb{C}^*$ admits a globally defined logarithm?

If the manifold $M$ has the homotopy lifting property with respect to the exponential map $e:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}^*$ I would be done, but I don't know if this is true. Maybe this property holds trivially for null-homotopies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just the lifting property for covering spaces. If $p:(C, c_0) \rightarrow (X,x_0)$ is a covering space and $f:(Z,z_0) \rightarrow (X,x_0)$ any pointed map from a path connected and locally path connected space $Z$. Then there exists a lift $g: Z \rightarrow C$ of $f$ iff $f_*(\pi_1(Z,z_0)) \subset p_*(\pi_1(C,c_0))$.

$f(z_0) = c_0$.

This lift $g$ is also unique up to choice of element of $p^{-1}(x_0)$ that $z_0$ gets mapped to under $g$.

Apply this to the situation $p = exp:(\mathbb C,0) \rightarrow (\mathbb C ^*,1)$ and $Z = M$ and you shall see that since $f$ is nullhomotopic that inclusion of fundamental groups holds trivially since $f_* = 0$, so there is indeed a lift $M \rightarrow \mathbb C$ by this covering theorem.